# jQuery delay on scrollTop function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to hide with an .animate a block when the user scroll to the top on the html, the thing is that when I got to the top it takes like 5sec to make the animation, I want the animation to trigger immediately, someone know how please?

```
// On scroll to top hide block 'Welcome'
$(document).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
        $("div#welcome_slide").animate({ "top": "0" }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the initial `top` position of your `div`?

Comment: 34px, when I scroll more than 100px the div shows and the position is -540px... so when I go to the top I want the div to animate top 34px again.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/574arm1w/

Comment: Now you can see the delay when scroll to top... is it because I have 2 functions..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/574arm1w/2/)

Please check if this is what you're trying to achieve.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
    var  animating = false;    
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var divTop = Number($('#slide').css('top').replace('px',''));
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 100 && !animating && divTop > 100) {
            // On scroll show block 'Welcome'
            animating = true;
            $("#slide").animate({ "top": 100+"px" }, 1000,function(){
            animating = false;
            });
            return false;
        }
        else if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0 && !animating && divTop < 480) {
                // On scroll to top hide block 'Welcome'
            console.log('0');
            animating = true;
            $("#slide").animate({ "top": 480+"px" }, 500,function(){
            animating = false;
            });
           return false;
        }        
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Too late but here's my answer anyway.

`.scroll()` is triggered MANY times whilst the user is scrolling. Therefore your animation is getting triggered LOTS of times. These animations are queued up - hence causing the long delay when hiding (its waiting till the end of the queue).

You can force the queue to end using [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to abort the animation before each call OR you can set a flag to test if the slide is revealed and only animate it accordingly:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    // On scroll show block 'Welcome'
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 100 && !$(this).data('revealed')) {
        $("#slide").stop().animate({ "top": "100px" }, 1000);
        $(this).data('revealed',true);
        return false;
    }

    // On scroll to top hide block 'Welcome'
    if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0) {
        $("#slide").stop().animate({ "top": "480px" }, 500);            
        $(this).removeData("revealed");
        return false;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/574arm1w/3/

Comment: a last thing, what's with adding a Data?

Comment: [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) is a method of storing arbitrary data associated with an element. Here we associate a variable (which I chose to call "revealed") with the `$(window)` object. On hiding the #slide we simply remove that piece of data. OnScroll we check if `'revealed'` has been set so that we can decide wether to run the animation or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.delay` in jquery

```
$("div#welcome_slide").delay(1000).animate({ "top": "0" }, 500);
```

or `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout((function() {
   $("div#welcome_slide").animate({top: 0} ,{duration:500});
}), 1000);
```

Comment: jsfiddle.net/574arm1w

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.I think this is your requirement.

```
$(document).scroll(function () {    
if ($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {    
    $("div#welcome_slide").slideUp(500);    
    }
})
```